# Trouble with Tooltips in Bootstrap 3 / Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble getting tooltips to work while attempting to follow [this example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) (under "Markup") from the official Bootstrap documentation.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="first tooltip">Hover over me</a>
```

Trigger the tooltip using Javascript:

```
$('#example').tooltip(options)
```

My question is whether or not I should add the javascript code (the "trigger" as it's referred to) to the header.php or if I should somehow enqueue it as a function in function.php (which I'm not sure how to do properly), or if I should even just put it in  tags on the page itself with the rest of the content. Nothing I've tried so far has worked properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger just needs to be fired once the element is loaded as well as jquery and the twitter bootstrap javascript has been loaded.

This also depends on your wordpress theme and how it has been setup.

Where are you putting in YOUR javascript?

If you've used bootstrap did you manually add the CSS and JS files to your theme? Or did you use Boilerplate as a base for the theme?

You want your JS to load after all other scripts have been initialized.

If you haven't included your own javascipt yet, I would suggest doing the following.

Create a main.js file and place it in a folder you make called 'js'.

In your footer.php (if you've got one in your theme), right before the `</body>` add:

```
<script src="js/main.js></script>
```

Then in your js file you'll want to add your 'trigger' call.

```
$('#example').tooltip(options)
```

Another problem you may be experiencing if your calling your trigger and the element isn't on the page. (Did you ajax that element into the page?)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I was eventually able to make it work by using the method you included (i.e. a "main.js") with this code:

    `jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#example').tooltip()
    });`

I think I have a conflict or two with how I'm calling jQuery, so I still have to sort that out, but this does work.

Comment: Ok cool I'm glad that helped. if you want to post a link to your project if you can host it, I would be glad to take a look into how jQuery is being initialized. Sounds like your dominos might be out of order so when one falls its not hitting the next one, if that makes sense... :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may not be including tooltip.js on your page.

Triggering tooltip via javascript is in case you want non default options.